# Can Nexus (Sonartype) be used with maven projects in the same way that we use SVN with Java EE projects to handle the version control?

Tags: java, svn, jakarta-ee, nexus

Can Nexus (Sonartype) be used with Maven projects in the same way that we use SVN with Java EE projects to handle the version control?

Answer (score 2):

No, Nexus is a Maven repository manager, its primary use is to store significant artefacts - e.g. versioned or 'snapshots' - emitted by your build process. It cannot be used as a replacement for a version control system.

I advise that you check out [Sonatype's site on Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/why) for further details.